# How to get penultimate monday of the month?

Tags: php

I can create `DateTime` Objects with string parameter to get dates, like this.

```
$first = new \DateTime("first monday of july 2015");
$second = new \DateTime("last tuesday of july 2015");
$third = new \DateTime("first monday of january 2015");
```

But how can i get penultimate monday of july?

Comment: you need to reword the tile of the question like 'how to get penultimate Monday of the month?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by DateInterval example

```
$last = new \DateTime("last monday of july 2015");
$penultimate = $last->sub(new \DateInterval('P7D'));
```

Variable $penultimate will be last Monday minus 7 days what is penultimate Monday of july

Answer (score 2):

```
$penultimateMonday = new \DateTime("last monday of july 2015 -1 week");

echo $penultimateMonday->format('Y-m-d');
```

**Output**

```
2015-07-20
```

Comment: @Uchiha- Thanks. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The penultimate mondoay of july is always 7 days before the last monday in july, so you can do:

```
$last = new \DateTime("last monday of july 2015");
$penultimate = $last -7;
```

Comment: I think you want to use: [`modify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) to subtract 1 week.

Comment: @sprague44 so easy, it's not my day :) i solve this in a smiliar way like this "$last = new \DateTime("last monday of july 2015");; $last->modify("-1 Week")" many thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
echo $test = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("last monday of july 2015"));
```

Comment: The penultimate Monday of a month is the Monday *before* the last Monday of a month.